# what is the intersection of two linear codes?

Tags: math, linear-algebra, error-detection

I have a question about linear codes. 
Let's say we have two `(n,k)` linear codes `C1` and `C2` with parity check matrix `H1` and `H2`. Is the intersection of `C1` and `C2` still a linear code? If so, what is its parity check matrix `H3` given `H1` and `H2`? `C3` is the intersection of `C1` and `C2` means `H1c3=0` and `H2c3=0` for all c3\in `C3`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is 100% about math.

Comment: no, it is not off topic since it is related to linear code, Hamming code and error detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is also a linear code.

A linear code of length `n` and rank `k` is a linear subspace `C` with dimension `k` of the vector space **V**.

Given subspaces **U** and **W** of a vector space **V**, then their intersection **U** ∩ **W** := {v ∈ **V** : v is an element of both **U** and **W**} is also a subspace of **V**.

To obtain H dimension this statement may be used:

Let (G,+G,∘)K be a K-vector space.
Let M and N be finite-dimensional subspaces of G.

Then M+N and M∩N are finite-dimensional, and:

dim(M+N) + **dim(M∩N)** = dim(M) + dim(N)

so:

dim(M+N) + **dim(M∩N)** = k1 + k2

where dim(M∩N) is new k of the intersection.

Comment: A subspace of V does not mean it is a linear code, right? For example, linear combinations of points in this subspace might not be in this subspace.

Comment: linear combination of points in subspace always belong to this subspace

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I guess you meant a linear subspace, not subspace. Do you have any idea how to find H3 based on H1 and H2?

Comment: of course, a linear code of length n and rank k is a **linear** subspace

Comment: H3 should have more rows than H1 and H2, since its null space is a linear subspace of null spaces of H1 and H2. The remaining question is, how can we find H3 based on H1 and H2.

Comment: I see, we can simply stack H1 and H2 together to get H3. H3=[H1;H2]